# how to determine functional dependencies and multivalued dependencies?

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

i have the following table

```
Case ( referenceID, startDate, endDate, caseDetail, caseType, caseTypeRate, 
    lawyerName, lawyerContact, clientID, clientName, clientAddress, clientContact,
    serviceProvided, serviceDate, serviceCost,
    otherPartyID, otherPartyName, otherPartyContact )
```

my FDs are

```
 referenceID-->caseDetail
 referenceID-->caseType
 referenceID-->ServiceProvided
 lawyerContact-->lawayerName
 clientID-->clientName
```

am i correct or are there more? i'm still a bit unsure of how it works after reading the theory. i need clear examples. how do i determine the mvds as well?

Answer (score 4):

Loosely speaking, a functional dependency expressed as `x -> y` means, "When I know any value of x, I know one and only one value of y." So the value of x determines one and only one value of y.

To determine whether a functional dependency exists, you ask yourself the question, "If I know any value for x, do I know one and only one value for y?", and then answer it.

In your case, I'd *guess* that *most* of these additional functional dependencies will hold. It's hard to tell for sure, since there's no sample data, and since I don't know what the columns mean. (Trying to determine functional dependencies based solely on column names is *very* risky. Here, "startDate" could mean just about anything.)

```
referenceID -> startDate
referenceID -> endDate
referenceID -> caseType
referenceID -> caseTypeRate
clientID -> clientName
clientID -> clientAddress
clientID -> clientContact
otherPartyID -> otherPartyName
otherPartyID -> otherPartyContact
```

There are others.

Wikipedia has a [concise example of a multi-valued dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency#Example).

Answer (score 4):

Functional dependency:-If one value for X there is only one value of Y then we can say that Y is functionaly dependent upon X and written as follow.

```
X -> Y
```

Multivalue dependecy:-If for one value of X there are more than one values of Y then we can say that Y is multivalue dependency upon X and it is written as followes.

```
X ->-> Y
```

Comment: No. For a table with attribute set R and attribute subsets X & Y, an MVD X  ->> Y holds when if an X value is in rows with a set of Y values then every X U (R - Y) value with that X value is in rows with that set of Y values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of how to determine a MVD: https://web.archive.org/web/20140212170321/https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jdonalds/311/lecture08.html.

Basically, follow this algorithm:

1) Figure out if A determines a set of values for B,
2) Figure out if A determines a set of values for C, and then
3) Determine if B and C are independent of each other.

A, B, C are a set of attributes.  If the conditions are satisfied then
A -->> B and A -->> C are MVDs.